# sonar analysis is failing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I'm using Eclipse Neon(which will support JDK 1.8) to open the eclipse I've set the Java_Home point to 1.8. I'm using the sonarqube 4.3.3

While analyzing the project in eclipse(set the project jdk to 1.6) for sonar i'm getting the below issues

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks & Regards,

Sangeetha Kannan

Comment: IIRC, 4.3 doesn't support Java 8. That may or may not be your problem, but 4.3 is nearly 3 years old. The current version is 6.3 & the current LTS is 5.6.6. You're going to have a very hard time finding help/support for 4.3. You should give serious thought to upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ann. We are planning for the up gradation to 5.6.6. In 5.6.6 we can able to get the author of the issues. Can you please describe the step how to auto assign the issues to the person who create the issues. -Sangeetha K